# Keeping an activity from re-creating my fragments on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I have an activity that holds a fragment, when something on that fragment gets clicked i replace that fragment with another fragment. If the device is rotated with in the second fragment then the `onCreate` gets called for the activity and recreates the first fragment again.

How can I stop the onCreate from getting called when the device rotates?

in my manifest i have this

```
<activity android:name="CalActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

it is my understanding that adding in the configChanges to that activity prevents the activity from being destroyed and recreated but the onCreate still gets called and messes up the fragments.

I also tried putting in `setRetainInstance()` in the fragments and that didnt help either

if the device does not rotate the the fragments work like they should and I dont want to make this a one orientation only activity, thats more of a hack than actually fixes the problem

What else can I do?

EDIT:

this is how I create my fragments

```
Fragment miniMonthFrag = new MonthByWeekFragment(System.currentTimeMillis(), false);
ft.replace(R.id.cal_frame, miniMonthFrag).commit();
```

Comment: How are you creating the fragments in the activity?

Comment: Try putting your Fragments in XML layout of the Activity, if they aren't there.

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller I edited my question to show how I create my fragments

Comment: @DoctororDrive putting my fragments in an xml will not work because I need dynamic fragments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using replace use:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.cal_frame) == null) {
        mFragment = new MonthByWeekFragment(System.currentTimeMillis(), false);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.cal_frame, mFragment ).commit();
    } else {
        mFragment = (MonthByWeekFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.cal_frame);
    }
```

This will make sure you use the pre-existing fragment after a rotate.

Comment: The month fragment is my base fragment for the activity so what happens when I go to another fragment? how can i differentiate what fragment is in the view because that view could and will get replaced with another fragment based on the click

Comment: You can give each fragment a different tag when you add it (3rd argument in add() method), or just check the type of the fragment you get back using an "if(fragment instanceof MyOtherFragmentClass) check.